# How to open a template from bottom to top like keyboard in xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard

I want to create a custom keyboard in xamarin forms that should work in android and ios. And device keyboard should hide when custom keyboard opens. My code is working fine in IOS. But when I am running it in android, generally keboard doesn't hide but then I used following code. but in that case the normal keyboard open for 2 milliseconds and then hide. I want the keyboard should never visible if focus comes in Entry box.

Initally I have an Entry field where normal device keyboard opens, then when user click on Return button of Keyboard focus changes to next Entry field where I need to open the custom keyboard, but in this case normal keyboard also opens if I don't use Handler for the code that use to hide android keyboard. When I use handler then keyboard opens for 2 ml then it hides. But I want to hide the keyboard permanently if focus comes in this Entry field. Following is the code that I am using in Entry renderer to hide the keyboard

```
   ((Entry)e.NewElement).Focused += delegate
                            {
                                this.Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
                                new Handler().PostDelayed(delegate
                                {
                                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                                    imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
                                    Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;
                                }, 200L);
                            };
```

How I can hide the android keyboard when focus comes from Completed event of previous entry box to next entry box.

Comment: Why not hide the Keyboard when the next entry has the focus? You can detect the focus event by the entry.